# MySQL: parallel restores at same time from backup files?

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, parallelism

Slightly related to this question, but for MySQL: [Would it be possible/wise to execute 2 parallel restores from a single backup?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20007/would-it-be-possible-wise-to-execute-2-parallel-restores-from-a-single-backup)

Is it possible/wise to do a parallel restore of two independent databases from two separate MySQL dump files?

Restoring one of them seems to only take up about 10% of CPU cycles consistently and takes a long time to finish, so I'm thinking that a second restore shouldn't cause any load problems - but might it cause any other MySQL/DB issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not be a problem as long as the data in the two dump files involves different tables... however, it may or may not be as helpful as you might hope, because if the single restore is only using 10% cpu, that suggests that your disk, as opposed to cpu, may be the more significant determining factor in limiting the speed of the restore.